# Use flexbox to center content while not making elements side by side

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am using flexbox to center content with `justify-content: center` which works as intended but flexbox also moves divs to be side by side which I don't want.

Here is an example

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I use flexbox while retaining the default one div on top of the other positioning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `flex-direction: column` and then you have to use `align-items: center`. Default `flex-direction` is `row`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  height 100px;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code,

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.content {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```